# Struggle to understand SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm struggling to understand what the below 2 chunks of code do. Some comments would be really appreciated.

Chunk 1:

```
    SELECT
        l
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                level l
            FROM
                dual
            CONNECT BY
                level <= 1000
        ),
        (
            SELECT
                level m
            FROM
                dual
            CONNECT BY
                level <= 1000
        )
```

Chunk 2:

```
    HAVING
        COUNT(
            CASE l / m
                WHEN trunc(l / m) THEN
                    'Y'
            END
        ) = 2
```

PD: I will post below the entire SQL query to provide more background. The query just gets the prime numbers 1 to 1000 and listaggs them with ampersands.

```
SELECT
    LISTAGG(l, '&') WITHIN GROUP(
        ORDER BY
            l
    )
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            l
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    level l
                FROM
                    dual
                CONNECT BY
                    level <= 1000
            ),
            (
                SELECT
                    level m
                FROM
                    dual
                CONNECT BY
                    level <= 1000
            )
        WHERE
            m <= l
        GROUP BY
            l
        HAVING
            COUNT(
                CASE l / m
                    WHEN trunc(l / m) THEN
                        'Y'
                END
            ) = 2
        ORDER BY
            l
    );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[TL;DR] It is a prime number generator.

---

```sql
SELECT level l FROM dual CONNECT BY level <= 1000
```

Generates 1000 rows containing incrementally increasing numbers from 1 to 1000 and aliases the column to `l`.

```sql
SELECT level m FROM dual CONNECT BY level <= 1000
```

Does exactly the same thing but aliases the column to `m`.

```sql
SELECT l
FROM   ( SELECT level l FROM dual CONNECT BY level <= 1000 ),
       ( SELECT level m FROM dual CONNECT BY level <= 1000 )
```

Applies a `CROSS JOIN` (using the legacy comma-join syntax) between the two tables and returns only the `l` column; so you will have 1000 copies of each of the numbers from 1 to 1000 (for a total of 1000000 rows)... or would do if there wasn't the filter condition:

```sql
WHERE m <= l
```

Which filters those rows so you don't get 1000 rows of each number but you will get 1 row with the `l` value of 1, 2 rows with the `l` value of 2 (with `m` values of 1 and 2), 3 rows with the value of 3 (with `m` values of 1, 2, and 3), ... etc. up to 1000 rows with the value of 1000 (with `m` values of 1, 2, 3, ..., 999, 1000).

```sql
GROUP BY l
HAVING COUNT( CASE l / m WHEN trunc(l / m) THEN 'Y' END ) = 2
```

Counts the number of factors of `l` (where the value `m` divides exactly into `l`) and filters to only have those rows where there are exactly two factors. Those factors must be the values when `m` equals `1` and `l`; which means that there are no other factors of `l` between the values of `1` and `l` and so `l` is a prime number.

```sql
ORDER BY l
```

Then orders the values in ascending order.

---

A more efficient generator would be:

```sql
SELECT 2 AS l FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS l FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT l
FROM   ( SELECT 2 * level + 3 l FROM dual CONNECT BY 2 * level + 3 <= 1000 )
       CROSS APPLY
       ( SELECT 2 * level + 1 m FROM dual CONNECT BY POWER(2 * level + 1, 2) <= l )
GROUP BY l
HAVING COUNT( CASE l / m WHEN trunc(l / m) THEN 1 END ) = 0
ORDER BY l
```

Which correlates the row generators to only generate odd numbers and so that the second generator stops generating at the square root of the value of the first generator.

Comment: Thanks for the amazing answer! In the having clause, which notation is that? I'm used to case when then end, but here it is slightly different.

Comment: I would have done it this way:         SUM(
            CASE
                WHEN mod(l, m) = 0 THEN
                    1
            END
        ) = 2 not sure if it's exactly the same.

Comment: @jeiv There are two valid syntaxes for a `CASE` expression. The Oracle documentation is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm). You appear to be used to the `searched_case_expression` syntax whereas the code in the question uses the `simple_case_expression` syntax.

Comment: Yes, using modulo to find the exact divisors is another similar method.

Comment: Thanks! One last question: for your generator:  ( SELECT 2 * level + 3 l FROM dual CONNECT BY 2 * level + 3 <= 1000 )
       CROSS APPLY
       ( SELECT 2 * level + 1 m FROM dual CONNECT BY POWER(2 * level + 1, 2) <= l ) how does this work? I'm struggling to understand the logic behind the connect by for these.

Comment: The first row generator generates odd numbers from 5 to 999. The second is correlated to the first generator using `CROSS APPLY` and generates odd numbers from 3 up to the square root of the first number (but it performs the comparison by squaring the second generated number and comparing it to the first generated number rather than using a more expensive square root operation on the first number).

Comment: Sorry, I'm still struggling to understand the concept of a cross join dependent on the previous one. :(

Comment: @jeiv Search for `CROSS APPLY` or `LATERAL` inline views.