# Connect by in cross apply

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below code:

```
SELECT
    m, l
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            2 * level + 3 l
        FROM
            dual
        CONNECT BY
            2 * level + 3 <= 1000
    ) CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
            2 * level + 1 m
        FROM
            dual
        CONNECT BY
            power(2 * level + 1, 2) <= l
    ) order by m, l
```

However, the first results shown are the below. Why is the 2nd power of m connecting with l in that case if power(3, 2) is not <= 5 (or 7)?

```
m   l
3   5
3   7
```

Comment: Your query has `cross apply` but your title says `cross join`. Do you think (or assume) they are the same thing? They most definitely aren't. Please fix either your join or your title.

Comment: @mathguy oh, I thought they were the same thing. That's the title updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `CONNECT BY` checks whether the query will recurse *after* the first row is generated so you will always get at least one row (where `LEVEL` is 1); if you want to limit the number of rows then you need a `START WITH` or `WHERE` clause.

You can see the difference if you also include either clause and `OUTER APPLY` to return the `l` rows when `m` then has no generated rows (and would be `NULL`):

```sql
SELECT m, l
FROM   ( SELECT 2 * level + 3 AS l
         FROM   dual
         CONNECT BY 2 * level + 3 <= 25 )
       OUTER APPLY
       ( SELECT 2 * level + 1 AS m
         FROM   dual
         START WITH 9 <= l
         CONNECT BY power(2 * level + 1, 2) <= l )
order by l, m
```

or

```sql
SELECT m, l
FROM   ( SELECT 2 * level + 3 AS l
         FROM   dual
         CONNECT BY 2 * level + 3 <= 25 )
       OUTER APPLY
       ( SELECT 2 * level + 1 AS m
         FROM   dual
         WHERE  power(2 * level + 1, 2) <= l
         CONNECT BY power(2 * level + 1, 2) <= l )
order by l, m
```

or
Outputs:

> | M | L |
> | --- | --- |
> |  | 5 |
> |  | 7 |
> | 3 | 9 |
> | 3 | 11 |
> | 3 | 13 |
> | 3 | 15 |
> | 3 | 17 |
> | 3 | 19 |
> | 3 | 21 |
> | 3 | 23 |
> | 3 | 25 |
> | 5 | 25 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e06f292bdd8ae83a48f3e062a6f69fd8)*

Comment: I didn't follow the problem closely; but, generally, if you want something checked for `level = 1`, you need a `start with` clause, not a `where` clause.

Comment: @mathguy That does not work if you try to use `LEVEL` in the `START WITH` clause; you still would get 1 row. You would need to hard code the minimum. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8711f5dc6728d4087e3f4dc573d22499)

Comment: @mathguy this is the original post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67509233/struggle-to-understand-sql-query/67509474#67509474

Comment: In your dbfiddle test, you get those rows because you used **outer** apply instead of **cross** apply. It's possible that the conditions won't work quite as expected with `level` in `start with`, because for some idiotic reason Oracle thinks `level = 0` then; but you can certainly hard-code 1 instead of `level` in `start with` if needed.

Comment: @mathguy As I said in the answer, I use `OUTER APPLY` exactly for the reason of showing those rows are not generated (and would appear as `NULL`) and, yes, you can hardcode the number (as I said in my previous comment).

Comment: The first query does not work for me :( I have Oracle Database 12c 12.1.0.2.0

Comment: @MT0 so, if the connect by will recurse after the first row is generated, why is the second one generated if the condition is not longer met?

Comment: @jeiv The second one is generated by `CONNECT BY` then filtered out by the `WHERE` clause and then the `OUTER APPLY` will return the `l` row with a `NULL` value for `m` (just like you would get if you used a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with a non-matching row).

Comment: No, I mean in the one with the CROSS APPLY

Comment: @jeiv Neither of the queries in my answer use `CROSS APPLY`.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. What I'm trying to understand here is this sentence: 'Because CONNECT BY checks whether the query will recurse after the first row is generated so you will always get at least one row (where LEVEL is 1)'

Comment: `SELECT * FROM DUAL` generates one row; if the statement continues with a `CONNECT BY` clause then Oracle will check to see if a second row is generated if it is then it will add that to the result set and then will repeat and check `CONNECT BY` for a third row, etc. At **NO** point is `CONNECT BY` used to check whether the first row should be generated so there will always be a first row (in the absence of a `START WITH` clause).

Comment: Ok, so, for that level one, no comparison is made and 3 (m) will be matched against all of the l values, am I correct? From m =5 on, the comparison is actually made.